# What's going on with the wall building on US-Mexico border in Summer 2021?

Tags: united-states, immigration, illegal-immigration, joe-biden, trump-wall

[Stopping the wall](https://www.business-standard.com/article/international/biden-s-order-to-stop-border-wall-construction-would-save-2-6-bn-report-120121700267_1.html) was part of Joe Biden's campaign points. And then, his administration [signed](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/pledging-build-trumps-border-wall-bidens-intentions-remain/story?id=76928099) an order on Inauguration Day ending the national emergency at the border and launching a 60-day review of the project, pausing all construction and calling for a plan to redirect unspent funds.

What's going on now with this wall? I've read some articles (for example, [this](https://nypost.com/2021/04/06/mayorkas-now-considering-filling-gaps-in-border-wall-report/)), mentioning that wall building would be continued, but I don't know, if they can be trusted.

Comment: Border wall is not a new thing. Extending/fixing the existing structure should not be surprising regardless of the president. I can't speak towards the validity of the article you have linked but I wouldn't be surprised if it were correct to some extent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AP [looked into this](https://apnews.com/article/fact-checking-607267725480)

> CLAIM: The U.S. Army Corps of Engineers is restarting border wall construction in the Rio Grande Valley.

> AP’S ASSESSMENT: Missing context. The U.S. Army Corps of Engineers clarified on Twitter that it has begun work to repair the Rio Grande Valley’s flood barrier system, which was previously partially excavated to make way for the border wall. The work does not involve expanding the border wall.

Apparently the abrupt stoppage of work [caused some damage](https://thehill.com/changing-america/resilience/refugees/553336-biden-administration-resumes-repairing-wall-on-southern)

> The Biden administration will repair a damaged southern border wall levee, not to be confused with building a wall to address immigration, they say.